# MongoDB update all subelements from subarray

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a following schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52dfba46daf02aa4630cf529"),
    "hotelVenue" : {
        "rooms" : [ 
            {
                "clientId" : "ROOM_1",
                "roomName" : "Executive"
            }, 
            {
                "clientId" : "ROOM_2",
                "roomName" : "Premium"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52dfc2f9daf02aa2632bc8af"),
    "hotelVenue" : {
        "rooms" : [ 
            {
                "clientId" : "ROOM_1",
                "roomName" : "Studio Room"
            }, 
            {
                "clientId" : "ROOM_2",
                "roomName" : "Soho Suite"
            }, 
            {
                "clientId" : "ROOM_3",
                "roomName" : "Luxury Suite"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to genearate unique id for all the records -> subarray. 
i.e., in the example there is rooms so for each and every room type, I need give a unique id basically using ObjectId().

Output should look something like the below, where roomId being generated.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52dfba46daf02aa4630cf529"),
    "hotelVenue" : {
        "rooms" : [ 
            {
                "clientId" : "ROOM_1",
                "roomName" : "Executive",
                "roomId" : "56f8cb3f0c658b4bc26172342"
            }, 
            {
                "clientId" : "ROOM_2",
                "roomName" : "Premium",
                "roomId" : "56f8cb3f0c658b4bc26176d4"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have written this script where it gives the following error: **Error: Line 9: Unexpected token +**

```
db.venues.find().forEach(function(data) 
{
    data.hotelVenue.rooms.forEach(function(roomItem) 
    {
        db.venues.update({_id:data._id,'data.hotelVenue.rooms.clientId' : roomItem.clientId},
        {
            $set:
            {
                'hotelVenue.rooms.'+roomItem.clientId+'.roomId' : ObjectId()
            }
        }); 
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This should do it in a more efficient manner by only saving each document once;

```js
db.venues.
  find({"hotelVenue.rooms": { $elemMatch: {roomId: {$exists: 0}}}}).
  forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.hotelVenue.rooms.forEach(function(room) {
      if(!room.roomId) {
        room.roomId = ObjectId();
      }
    }); 
    db.venues.save(doc);
  });
```

The `find` filters out only documents that are in need of updating. After that, it's just a matter of updating the document as needed and calling `save`.

Of course, backups are in order before running potentially destructive queries from random people on the Internet against your production data set.

Comment: Joachim, when i run the query which you have provided its gives the error has **TypeError: result has no properties (shell):7**

Comment: @sharath Which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: version : 2.6.10.  Running this in ubuntu''s robomongo

Comment: doing it locally as of now if everything works fine, then i'll run on production db

Comment: ya sure, i'll be waiting for your reply

Comment: @Sharath Works for me on 2.6.11 using the mongo shell. Don't have robomongo to test with. If you can't make it work, you may want to look at the question this was marked as a duplicate of.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, i'll take a look into it.

Comment: @Sharath Updated with a version that - once again - works for me on 2.6, you may want to take a look.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, it works...